# Empty picklist shown on Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

> **Controller**

```
public class controller{

public List<SelectOption> States{get;set;}
public List<SelectOption> cities{get;set;}

public String selectedState{get;set;}
public String selectedcity{get;set;}

public void getpickvalues(){
    States = new List<SelectOption>();
    cities = new List<SelectOption>();

    States.add(new SelectOption('','--None--'));
    States.add(new SelectOption('UP','UP'));
    States.add(new SelectOption('MP','MP'));

    cities.add(new SelectOption('','--None--'));
    cities.add(new SelectOption('Meerut','Meerut'));
    cities.add(new SelectOption('Indore','Indore'));
   }
}
```

> **VF Page**

```
<apex:pageBlock>     
    <apex:outputLabel> States: </apex:outputLabel>
    <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!selectedState}">
        <apex:selectOption value="{!States}" />
    </apex:selectList>
    </apex:pageBlock>


</apex:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your tag from

```
<apex:selectOption value="{!States}" />
```

to

```
<apex:selectOptions value="{!States}"/>
```

According to this documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_selectList.htm).